# autolayout on Uiimageview height inside scrollview uiview not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8

I have a large form and i used scrollview in swift 3 , from storyboard i take scrollview and inside that 1 uiview.
I add uiimageview for logo and add constraints equal width and equal height with 79:667 but width is resize according to screen size but height not resize.
I checked same in uitableview and same issue 
Xcode 8 and swift 3

Comment: You should include the code

Comment: I have done using storyboard

Comment: Only height of image is not increase/decrease according to screen size in uiview which is inside scrollview

Comment: Hi @RaviThakur You got any luck? I am having the same issue